# Why does my pepper plant have yellowing, drying and curling leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, indoors, leaves, peppers

One of my pepper plants has so far suffered from [pests](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1223/), [blossom end rot](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1757/) and [odd skin blemishes](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/2028/) and unfortunately the plant is now taking a turn for the worse and looking rather unhealthy.

The leaves are drying out and curling along some edges, and they aren't very green (yellowing?).

### The unhealthy plant:

You can see the largest dry patch in the first image - the front of a leaf, while the second is the back of a leaf to demonstrate the loss of colour - compare it to the shots below.
[image: Unhealthy plant: front of leaf showing dry curling edge]
[image: Unhealthy plant: back of leaf showing curling edge and weak colour]

### Another healthier plant (for comparison):

This plant sat next to the unhealthy one, about a foot away on the same window sill, so conditions should be very similar. Images are again front then back of two leaves.
[image: Health plant: front of leaf. For comparison]
[image: Health plant: back of leaf. For comparison]

A few other points that may be relevant

- This is an indoor potted plant, it hasn't been moved in months.
- Fruit has been produced and harvested (although the first few with blossom end rot, as mentioned).
- It's watered with the same regularity as its peers.
- Water isn't being absorbed as much as with its peers - more ends up in the tray underneath, forcing me to give it less water to avoid overflowing.
  *This is unrelated to the issue raised in [another](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1453/) question of mine - that was a different plant.*

What could be wrong with the unhealthy plant?
What can I do to help it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your plant is pot bound (also known as root bound). The solution here is to purchase a bigger pot or transplant it into the garden. Based on the time of year and the fact that its an indoor pot I'd say that a larger pot would probably be the best solution.

[Mike](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/394/mike-perry) posted some [links](http://urbanext.illinois.edu/houseplants/caring_repot.cfm) to [repotting](http://extension.missouri.edu/p/G6510#Repotting) that you can use to guide your repotting process.